# XAMPP wordpress plugin - uploading media

Tags: wordpress, xampp

I'm experiencing an issue with a Wordpress plugin called CCGallery. I’m trying to get this to work localised on Wordpress using XAMPP – I can’t seem to upload images – it is saying upload failed:

```
http://localhost/websitename/wp-content/uploads/ccgallery-upload/undefined
```

...where undefined should be the file name.

I have set read and write permissions on the ccgallery-upload folder but it still doesn’t work.

Any ideas? – many thanks 
Al

Comment: Ok - I have tried exactly the same setup on a PC and it works fine - it must be a configuration setting?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sorry, I am not allowed to post a comment, but could you trying chmod full permissions to the whole websitename directory, and work you way from there? It seems like a permission issue.